# Rails - f.file_field says 'no chosen file after selecting and submitting'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I just followed railscast 134 to install paperclip into my rails 3.0.1 app. I did everything necessary but when I select a file and press submit on my form, it reloads the page and says "no file chosen"

This is in my events model:

```
 has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" },
                    :url  => "/assets/events/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/events/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment_presence :photo
  validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 
                                                              'image/png', 
                                                              'image/jpg']
```

and my form:

```
<h1>Edit Event</h1>
<%= form_for @event, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %><br /><br />
        <%= f.label :description %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :description %><br /><br />
        <%= f.label :event_date %><br />
        <%= text_field_tag :event_date, @event.event_date.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y at %I:%M%p"), :size=>30 %><br /><br />
        <%= f.label :location %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :location %><br /><br />
        <%= f.file_field :photo %><br /><br />
        <%= f.submit "Update" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

can't quite figure it out. thanks!

EDIT: some paperclip code in my event model:

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" },
                    :url  => "/assets/events/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/events/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment_presence :photo
  validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 
                                                              'image/png', 
                                                              'image/jpg']
```

and some debug output:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"hScfg9tx/4gBOHrtg+u8MB+QeUWS1sKtlcbnzK8YmRI=", "event"=>{"name"=>"Park", "description"=>"Swimming", "location"=>"Golden Gate Park", "photo"=>#<File:/var/folders/lm/5svv8x4s4d50yhw_h05qz7mm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20111023-6938-8xsv50>}, "event_date"=>"10/10/2011 at 02:00PM", "commit"=>"Update", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"events", "id"=>"3"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure that's normal behavior for a file_field, It only displays the file name when you select it to upload, it doesn't show the existing file saved in the Database.

If you want to display and access uploaded content try something like this in your view:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(@event.photo.url(:small)), @event.photo.url) %>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear - This actually happens when creating a new event and selecting an image as well as editing an event. I'm not trying to get it to display the uploaded file, I am only trying to get it to upload a file. When I select a file and press 'submit' it doesn't actually do that.

Comment: Do you have a 'attr_accessible' for your :photo object in your event model e.g.
attr_accessible :photo

Comment: @ Barlow Yes. I have that in my event.rb (event model). I edited my question to include the other stuff I have in there.

Comment: I got the image upload to work by commenting out :styles => { :small => "150x150>" } however now it stores the fullsize image. does that mean i need to install imagemagick? I can't seem to figure out how to do that, bundle always says cannot find gem

Comment: I'd say yes, Imagemagick is platform dependant, if your on a Mac use [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew), Ubuntu has a package, Windows has a [binary](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows)